# Cropped vector tiles in OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I have posted two questions regarding vector tiles on Stackoverflow ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466547/vector-tiles-buffer) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234804/ol3-geoserver-vector-tile-labels-gets-cropped)) but perhaps this is a better place to post it. I have a issue with lines and labels being sliced at the edge of the tiles as seen in the links.

Since this is not the expected behaviour I am wondering if anyone has a solution för this? Using the renderBuffer option when setting up the vectortilelayer makes no difference and I do not know what to try else. Output from Geoserver seems fine. The EPSG used is 3008 but I recall seeing the same behaviour when using 3857.

EDIT: I have now tested using GeoJSON and TopoJSON instead of MVT format and this makes the tiles look as expected. However, labeling is still an issue. And performance since GeoJSON/TopoJSON returns `ol.Feature` instead of `ol.render.Feature`